# Hibernate mapping with abstract parent class

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have an abstract class holding a number of fields which are inherited by numerous child classes.

Child classes have their own fields as well not just the ones inherited by this parent abstract class.

How do I map these attributes coming from parent abstract class to hibernate mapping file or with hibernate annotations, to save them in the database?

Each child class has its own table.

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler I don't know what to try, that is the point, I've dealt before with hibernate but not with abstract classes fields to database.

Comment: Try looking at the docs on JBoss: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Comment: That's no excuse for not trying. I mean, have you tried putting annotations on the parent class? Have you tried mapping the fields like you normally would in an HBM file? Those would be my first approaches. The Hibernate documentation is helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using annotations you can add this to your abstract class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    ...
```

And then map the fields in that class as you normally would.